# combining removing of numbers and underscores regex javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am awful at regex, and have been trying to teach myself.

In order to practice I am trying to remove all numbers and an underscores from a string.

I have been able to remove the numbers with the following, but the combination of both is bamboozling me.

```
var name = $(this).attr('id').replace(/\d+/g, '');
```

I am not sure how to combine the two. The following is one of my many efforts but to no avail.

```
var name = $(this).attr('id').replace(/\d+/\/_/g, '');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a character class `[\d_]` that will match a digit or an underscore.

Here is a small demo:

```js
console.log("Some_1234_6789 demo.".replace(/[\d_]+/g, ''))
```

Answer (score 0):

Also Use this

```
$(this).attr('id').replace(/_|\d+/g,'');
```

or

```
$(this).attr('id').replace(/[_\d]+/g,'')
```